# How can I print the car and cdr for the consed object in this code if they are integers?

Tags: c, mit-scheme

I am trying to build a cross compiler that implements scheme in c. For this I am trying to implement the basic scheme structure using cons and lists. The code which is shown below is for cons. I am not able to access the car of a consed object when it's an integer and not another consed object.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef enum
  {PAIR, NUMBER} object;

typedef struct node cons_object;

struct node {
  object type;
  union 
  {     
    int i;
    float f;
    char* string;
    struct pair {
      cons_object* car;
      cons_object* cdr;
    } pair;
  } data;
};

cons_object* cons(cons_object* x, cons_object* y)
{
  cons_object* obj;
  obj = malloc(sizeof(cons_object*));
  obj->type = PAIR;
  obj->data.pair.car = x;
  obj->data.pair.cdr = y;
  return obj; /*returns the pointer car*/
}

cons_object* car(cons_object* list) /*takes in a consed object*/
{
  cons_object* y;
  y = list->data.pair.car;
  return y;        /* returns the pointer of another consed object */
}

cons_object* cdr(cons_object* list)
{
  cons_object* z;
  z = list->data.pair.cdr;
  return z;         /* returns the pointer of another consed object */ 
}

void eval_cons(cons_object* pair) 
{
  cons_object* first;
  cons_object* second;
  int *a;                      /* An integer type pointer to dereference the values returned by car and cdr         pointers */

  first = car(pair);
  second = cdr(pair);
 {
   if(first->type == PAIR){
     eval_cons(first);        // If car is a cons-ed object, it is again sent to the eval function
   }
   else
 {
   a = (int *)&first; /* tried type casting too */ 
   printf("%d",*a);
 }
 }
 if(second->type == PAIR)         
   eval_cons(second); // If cdr is a cons-ed object, it is again sent to the eval function

 else 
   {
     a = (int *)&second;
     printf("%d",*a);             // prints the dereferenced value
   }
}

// If eval starts working then we could test it from the following sample code:


int main ()

{
  eval_cons(cons(3,4)); /* cant find a way to access 3 and 4 */
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're passing into cons two integers, not pointers to other cons objects.  what you need to do is make a cons function that turns integers into cons objects, and then call cons(cons_object * x/y on it).  With these two integers (3 and 4), you need to then malloc a cons object (so it persists) and then turn 3,4 pair into a cons object if thats any clearer: cons_object* cons(int x, int y)

Comment: even if I make 3 and 4 consed object, still I can't access them because there is no way to access integers in this case

Comment: sizeof(cons_object*) is wrong.  You're only returning 4 or 8 bytes (32/64 bit dependent) if you malloc the size of a pointer.  All pointers just need enough space to hold an address.  Your struct needs to be malloc'd to the size of your struct, and should be malloc(sizeof(struct cons_object));  Then when you access the pointers inside you will have to malloc as well.  So when you want to put values in the char * string, you'll have to malloc enough space, return this address to string, and then memcpy what you want into that location.  Same for the cons pointers.

Comment: Are you just trying to access `second->i`?

Comment: but whatever I put in for cons as arguments goes to the car and cdr pointers instead of i, so how can the integers be located at the address of i?

Comment: But at least he doesn't cast the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: @user2585933: "but whatever I put in for cons as arguments goes to the car and cdr pointers instead of i, so how can the integers be located at the address of i?" - by writing your functions differently?

Comment: look the car and cdr functions return me pointers to other structs so how can I retrieve an integer from them. Unless I somehow put there values  at the address of i instead of a pair

Comment: But *you have written* all these functions, so you can make them do something else, if you want to. You have to pass a pointer to a struct to both `car` and `cdr`, so why call those functions at all? Just access `i` from the struct you already have. You don't seem to have a clear idea what you are trying to achieve, which is always going to make things difficult.

Comment: I would like comments with downvotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
eval_cons(cons(3,4));
```

maybe, should be

```
cons_object a = { NUMBER, .data.i = 3};
cons_object b = { NUMBER, .data.i = 4};
eval_cons(cons(&a, &b));
```

also

```
int a;
a = first->data.i;//also second
printf("%d ",a);
```

Comment: But this way this function won't work for cases where I'll have another consed object at the car and cdr places. That is why I m using a PAIR tag for each consed object

Comment: @user2585933 Well think  once again.